# Non recursive tar listing

Tags: directory, tar

I have a tar archive file containing a directory with lots of files and I desire to list just that directory without extracting it (to hastenly know that directory's filename).
I executed:

```
tar -tf filename.tar.gz
```

Execution outputs recursively while I desire just the directory.
How could I "filter" just that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all names from the top level of a `tar` archive:

```
tar -tf archive.tar | cut -d '/' -f 1 | sort -u
```

This would list the contents of the archive and cut out the first bit before the `/` on each line.  The result is sorted and duplicates are removed.  If the archive only contains a single top-level directory (possibly with files and subdirectories within it), the result would be the name of that directory.

If the top-level names contains newlines, then the result would depend on what `tar` implementation is being used (you'd get a string with an encoded newline (`\n`) with GNU `tar` (GNU `tar` would likewise encode tabs and possibly other characters in names), and two separate strings from BSD `tar`).

Example:

```
$ tar -tf archive.tar
README.txt
source
source/program.c
```

```
$ tar -tf archive.tar | cut -d '/' -f 1 | sort -u
README.txt
source
```

Again, if the archive only contains a single directory at its uppermost level, this would have returned its name.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnuchess-6.2.5.tar.gz` as an example, to get just the root directory name:

```
[David@Fedora64 projects]$ tar -tf gnuchess-6.2.5.tar.gz | grep -e "\/$" | head -n1
gnuchess-6.2.5/
[David@Fedora64 projects]$
```

And if that that does nothing, as with a file structured like `mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz`, you can get the root directory name by just taking a look at the first line from the `tar` file:

```
[David@Fedora64 Downloads]$ tar -tf mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz | head -n1
mediawiki-1.33.0/.phan/config.php
[David@Fedora64 Downloads]$
```

...where the root directory is seen to be `mediawiki-1.33.0`.

Comment: The question states that the task is to get the name of the directory. Presumably, the archive contains a top-level directory whose name is unknown.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that, and was editing to post something more on point just as you commented. :)

Comment: @DavidYockey `tar -tf mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz | grep -e "\/$" | head -n1` didn't output the directory file, maybe you meant a slightly different syntax.

Comment: That syntax works at my end. I'll download `mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz` and see what happens with that.

Comment: Turns out `mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz` doesn't have the directories separately delineated. But we've been thinking too much... There's an easy way to get what your after... Just skim off the first line of `tar -tf mediawiki-1.33.0.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tar -tf mytar.tar | tree -L 1 --fromfile # show top level
```